# how to handle Set properties in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an object, `EventReminder`, that contains 2 Set objects:

```
var importantDates: Set<NSDate>
var recurringDays: Set<DayOfWeek>
.
.
.
enum DayOfWeek: Int {
    case Sunday = 0
    case Monday
    case Tuesday
    case Wednesday
    case Thursday
    case Friday
    case Saturday
}
```

I want to convert this to CoreData but I'm having trouble mapping it all out. My class has a many-to-many relationship with NSDate(via importantDates) and DayOfWeek(via recurringDays).

Do I:

1. make 2 classes of `importantDates` and `recurringDays` that hold only 1 property each: `NSDate` and `DayOfWeek`?
2. create a relationship between `EventReminder` and these 2 classes?
3. Do I have to make the enum `DayOfWeek` compliant to NSCoding? (not really sure if this is even possible)

Am I on the right track for the solution or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make a seperate NSManagedObject just to hold an NSDate or an enum.

You can store a Set in CoreData, just make the type transformable with custom class Set.